# Python: Agregar diccionarios a una lista dentro de un bucle

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, diccionarios

Tengo el siguiente código, donde `archivo` es un fichero .txt del que quiero extraer cierta información:

```
        arreglo = archivo.read().splitlines()  #Carga el archivo línea a línea

        datos = []
        trio = {}

        for linea in arreglo:

            if linea.find(').') != -1: trio['titulo_cancion'] = Utilidades.cancion(False, linea)
            if linea.find('tema:') != -1: trio['enlace_cancion_youtube'] = Utilidades.enlaceYT1(linea)
            if linea.find('alternativo:') != -1:
                trio['enlace_alternativo'] = Utilidades.enlaceYT2(linea)
                datos.append(trio)
                print(trio)
                print(datos)
```

Esperaría que al finalizar el bucle tuviera una lista con 15 diccionarios distintos en su interior; sin embargo, tengo una lista con los quince iguales (el último):

```
{'titulo_cancion': 'Great British mistake', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hykhOUMuPv8', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkLCuFHG8ak'}
[{'titulo_cancion': 'Great British mistake', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hykhOUMuPv8', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkLCuFHG8ak'}]
{'titulo_cancion': "Ever fallen in love (with someone you shouldn't've?)", 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1iD1R4jLmo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Af7ayYIJ9w'}
[{'titulo_cancion': "Ever fallen in love (with someone you shouldn't've?)", 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1iD1R4jLmo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Af7ayYIJ9w'}, {'titulo_cancion': "Ever fallen in love (with someone you shouldn't've?)", 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1iD1R4jLmo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Af7ayYIJ9w'}]
{'titulo_cancion': 'Surrender', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JpzQEdIP6A', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fIt9Alo39Q'}
[{'titulo_cancion': 'Surrender', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JpzQEdIP6A', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fIt9Alo39Q'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Surrender', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JpzQEdIP6A', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fIt9Alo39Q'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Surrender', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JpzQEdIP6A', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fIt9Alo39Q'}]
{'titulo_cancion': 'Tommy Gun', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqYgpJ6AqaA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFHEuKkTa5k'}
[{'titulo_cancion': 'Tommy Gun', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqYgpJ6AqaA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFHEuKkTa5k'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Tommy Gun', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqYgpJ6AqaA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFHEuKkTa5k'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Tommy Gun', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqYgpJ6AqaA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFHEuKkTa5k'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Tommy Gun', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqYgpJ6AqaA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFHEuKkTa5k'}]
{'titulo_cancion': 'Gut feeling', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3G8Cf47mi8c', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MapuX-qMrk8'}
[{'titulo_cancion': 'Gut feeling', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3G8Cf47mi8c', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MapuX-qMrk8'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Gut feeling', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3G8Cf47mi8c', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MapuX-qMrk8'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Gut feeling', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3G8Cf47mi8c', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MapuX-qMrk8'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Gut feeling', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3G8Cf47mi8c', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MapuX-qMrk8'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Gut feeling', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3G8Cf47mi8c', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MapuX-qMrk8'}]
{'titulo_cancion': 'No action', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vscYQV9AH48', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-CY_bV8TzE'}
[{'titulo_cancion': 'No action', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vscYQV9AH48', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-CY_bV8TzE'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'No action', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vscYQV9AH48', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-CY_bV8TzE'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'No action', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vscYQV9AH48', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-CY_bV8TzE'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'No action', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vscYQV9AH48', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-CY_bV8TzE'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'No action', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vscYQV9AH48', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-CY_bV8TzE'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'No action', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vscYQV9AH48', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-CY_bV8TzE'}]
{'titulo_cancion': 'One hundred punks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKnmaKBA8uo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}
[{'titulo_cancion': 'One hundred punks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKnmaKBA8uo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'One hundred punks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKnmaKBA8uo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'One hundred punks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKnmaKBA8uo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'One hundred punks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKnmaKBA8uo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'One hundred punks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKnmaKBA8uo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'One hundred punks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKnmaKBA8uo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'One hundred punks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKnmaKBA8uo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}]
{'titulo_cancion': 'English rose', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9I2C9wX5b7U', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}
[{'titulo_cancion': 'English rose', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9I2C9wX5b7U', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'English rose', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9I2C9wX5b7U', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'English rose', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9I2C9wX5b7U', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'English rose', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9I2C9wX5b7U', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'English rose', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9I2C9wX5b7U', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'English rose', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9I2C9wX5b7U', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'English rose', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9I2C9wX5b7U', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'English rose', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9I2C9wX5b7U', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}]
{'titulo_cancion': 'So it goes', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCxUSl98ElU', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEpr8kaczck'}
[{'titulo_cancion': 'So it goes', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCxUSl98ElU', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEpr8kaczck'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'So it goes', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCxUSl98ElU', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEpr8kaczck'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'So it goes', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCxUSl98ElU', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEpr8kaczck'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'So it goes', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCxUSl98ElU', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEpr8kaczck'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'So it goes', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCxUSl98ElU', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEpr8kaczck'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'So it goes', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCxUSl98ElU', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEpr8kaczck'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'So it goes', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCxUSl98ElU', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEpr8kaczck'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'So it goes', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCxUSl98ElU', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEpr8kaczck'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'So it goes', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCxUSl98ElU', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEpr8kaczck'}]
{'titulo_cancion': 'Ça plane pour moi', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VpQbeqTRcM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln31raI2ezY'}
[{'titulo_cancion': 'Ça plane pour moi', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VpQbeqTRcM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln31raI2ezY'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Ça plane pour moi', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VpQbeqTRcM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln31raI2ezY'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Ça plane pour moi', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VpQbeqTRcM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln31raI2ezY'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Ça plane pour moi', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VpQbeqTRcM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln31raI2ezY'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Ça plane pour moi', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VpQbeqTRcM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln31raI2ezY'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Ça plane pour moi', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VpQbeqTRcM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln31raI2ezY'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Ça plane pour moi', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VpQbeqTRcM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln31raI2ezY'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Ça plane pour moi', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VpQbeqTRcM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln31raI2ezY'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Ça plane pour moi', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VpQbeqTRcM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln31raI2ezY'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Ça plane pour moi', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VpQbeqTRcM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln31raI2ezY'}]
{'titulo_cancion': 'I wanna be sedated', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dywE0eXTltA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm51ihfi1p4'}
[{'titulo_cancion': 'I wanna be sedated', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dywE0eXTltA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm51ihfi1p4'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'I wanna be sedated', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dywE0eXTltA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm51ihfi1p4'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'I wanna be sedated', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dywE0eXTltA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm51ihfi1p4'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'I wanna be sedated', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dywE0eXTltA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm51ihfi1p4'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'I wanna be sedated', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dywE0eXTltA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm51ihfi1p4'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'I wanna be sedated', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dywE0eXTltA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm51ihfi1p4'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'I wanna be sedated', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dywE0eXTltA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm51ihfi1p4'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'I wanna be sedated', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dywE0eXTltA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm51ihfi1p4'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'I wanna be sedated', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dywE0eXTltA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm51ihfi1p4'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'I wanna be sedated', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dywE0eXTltA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm51ihfi1p4'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'I wanna be sedated', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dywE0eXTltA', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm51ihfi1p4'}]
{'titulo_cancion': 'Top of the pops', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQGgw8CVUs', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZ_plpJGCM'}
[{'titulo_cancion': 'Top of the pops', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQGgw8CVUs', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZ_plpJGCM'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Top of the pops', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQGgw8CVUs', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZ_plpJGCM'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Top of the pops', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQGgw8CVUs', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZ_plpJGCM'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Top of the pops', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQGgw8CVUs', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZ_plpJGCM'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Top of the pops', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQGgw8CVUs', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZ_plpJGCM'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Top of the pops', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQGgw8CVUs', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZ_plpJGCM'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Top of the pops', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQGgw8CVUs', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZ_plpJGCM'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Top of the pops', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQGgw8CVUs', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZ_plpJGCM'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Top of the pops', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQGgw8CVUs', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZ_plpJGCM'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Top of the pops', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQGgw8CVUs', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZ_plpJGCM'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Top of the pops', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQGgw8CVUs', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZ_plpJGCM'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Top of the pops', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQGgw8CVUs', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZ_plpJGCM'}]
{'titulo_cancion': 'Know your product', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPZ4CrcWIvo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9M3b9lh-7s'}
[{'titulo_cancion': 'Know your product', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPZ4CrcWIvo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9M3b9lh-7s'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Know your product', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPZ4CrcWIvo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9M3b9lh-7s'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Know your product', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPZ4CrcWIvo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9M3b9lh-7s'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Know your product', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPZ4CrcWIvo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9M3b9lh-7s'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Know your product', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPZ4CrcWIvo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9M3b9lh-7s'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Know your product', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPZ4CrcWIvo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9M3b9lh-7s'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Know your product', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPZ4CrcWIvo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9M3b9lh-7s'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Know your product', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPZ4CrcWIvo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9M3b9lh-7s'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Know your product', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPZ4CrcWIvo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9M3b9lh-7s'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Know your product', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPZ4CrcWIvo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9M3b9lh-7s'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Know your product', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPZ4CrcWIvo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9M3b9lh-7s'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Know your product', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPZ4CrcWIvo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9M3b9lh-7s'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Know your product', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPZ4CrcWIvo', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9M3b9lh-7s'}]
{'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}
[{'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Teenage kicks', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsNqjDdm6aM', 'enlace_alternativo': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PinCg7IGqHg'}]
{'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}
[{'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}, {'titulo_cancion': 'Outdoor miner', 'enlace_cancion_youtube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYem1Va4B6M', 'enlace_alternativo': 'NULL'}]
```

¿Es algún problema de paso por valor/referencia? ¿`append()` no es la función apropiada para este caso?

Comment: Mueve la línea `trio = {}` dentro del `for

Comment: No sirve, ya había probado.

Comment: En cada iteración reemplazas los valores de `trio` y luego lo insertas en la lista. La lista NO guarda los valores de `trio`; simplemente guarda una *referencia* a `trio`. Entonces tienes una lista de 15 referencias a un mismo objeto (`trio`), lo que te da todos los elementos iguales.

Comment: Poniendo `trio = {}` tras `datos.append(trio)`, funciona. Estoy haciendo la traducción de este guion desde PHP y no tenía este problema. ¿Sería posible que la lista no guardase la referencia sino el valor?

Comment: Ni idea de PHP.

Comment: Ya, digo en Python, si es posible hacer que el pase sea por valor en vez de por referencia y no tener que vaciar el diccionario en cada iteración.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139900/discussion-between-candid-moe-and-javier-blanco).